# ASP.NET DotNetOpenAuth Facebook logon without secret answer (requiresQuestionAndAnswer)

Tags: asp.net, facebook, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to allow users logging on to my ASP.NET website through their Facebook account. My website already has a classic registration page which asks the user for a secret question/answer for lost password retrieval. This is not necessary for Facebook logons, but I want to keep the security question for the other ones. Problem now is when I try to connect through facebook, the site throws an exception because the security question is missing. The Facebook logon works fine when I set the web.config file not to ask for the security question (requiresQuestionAndAnswer=false)

Any ideas how I can have both logons on my webstite?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

By default the 'create user' method is used in 'RegisterExternalLogin.aspx' page.

var createResult = OpenAuth.CreateUser(ProviderName, ProviderUserId, ProviderUserName, UserName.Text);

You can change the method to the one below and that should take care of it.

var createResult = OpenAuth.CreateUser(ProviderName, ProviderUserId, ProviderUserName, UserName.Text, "SomePassword", "Email", "Security Question?", "Security Answer");